# Displaying bar Code in PDF file on every page of the PDF, in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-9

## **I am Using Imagick to Convert PDF to Images**

## Uploading PDF to Laravel

```
public function uploadPdf( Request $request )
    {
        $model = new Attachment();
        if ( $request->hasFile('pdf_file_from_request') ) {
            Storage::deleteDirectory('3pagerpdf/pdf');
            $pdf      = $request->file('pdf_file_from_request');
            $fileName = time() . '.' . $pdf->getClientOriginalName();
            Storage::putFileAs('3pagerpdf/pdf', $pdf, $fileName);
            $model->pdf_file_name_in_datebase = $fileName;
            $model->save();
            flash()->addSuccess('Pdf Added');
            return back();
        }
    }
```

## Converting that PDF to Images

```
public function convertpdftoimages()
    {

        $model = Attachment::first();

        set_time_limit(300);
        // Get the PDF file from the storage folder
        $pdfPath = storage_path('app/3pagerpdf/pdf/'.$model->pdf_file_name_in_datebase);

        // Create an Imagick object
        $imagick = new Imagick();

        // Set the resolution and output format
        $imagick->setResolution(300, 300);
        $imagick->setFormat('jpeg');

        // Read the PDF file into the Imagick object
        $imagick->readImage($pdfPath);

        // Convert each page of the PDF to an image
        foreach ( $imagick as $page ) {
            $page->writeImage(public_path("/temp_images/page{$page->getImageIndex()}.jpg"));
        }

        flash()->addSuccess('Convertion Successfull');
        return back();
    }
```

## Adding bar code to those images

```
public function add_bar_code_to_images2()
    {

        $files = File::files('temp_images');

        foreach ( $files as $file ) {
            // Generate a barcode image for the file
            $barcodeGenerator = new BarcodeGeneratorPNG();
            $data = '';
            for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
                $data .= rand(0, 9);
            }
            $barcodeString = $barcodeGenerator->getBarcode($data, $barcodeGenerator::TYPE_CODE_128);

            // Create an image resource from the barcode string
            $barcodeImage = imagecreatefromstring($barcodeString);
            // Load the original image
            $originalImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($file->getPathname());

            // Merge the barcode image with the original image
            imagecopy($originalImage, $barcodeImage, imagesx($originalImage) - imagesx($barcodeImage) - 10, 10, 0, 0, imagesx($barcodeImage), imagesy($barcodeImage));

            // Save the modified image to a new path
            imagejpeg($originalImage, 'modified_images/' . $file->getFilename());
        }


        flash()->addSuccess('Bar Code Added Succesfuully');
        return back();


    }
```

## Converting those images Back to pdf

```
 public function convertimagestopdf(  )
    {
        // Create a new Imagick object
        $imagick = new Imagick();

        // Set the resolution of the PDF
        $imagick->setResolution(300, 300);

        // Iterate over the images in the "modified_images" directory
        foreach (glob("modified_images/*.jpg") as $image) {
            // Read the image file
            $imagick->readImage($image);
        }

        // Set the format of the PDF to "application/pdf"
        $imagick->setImageFormat('pdf');

        // Save the PDF to a file
        $imagick->writeImages('modified_pdf/document.pdf', true);
        flash()->addSuccess('pdf compileed');
        return back();


    }
```

## What I want is

I want to add bar code to every single page of a pdf but I dont want to use imagick extenstion it needs to be installed on a system to make it work .

## I tried the above code

it is taking too long to execute for small pdf's that code it fine but for the pdf with 60 pages and above it starts to give me time out error

## Note I am not generating this pdf

the pdf will be uploaded by random user of my application and it will be already a pdf I just need to add barcode to every single page of the pdf .

## I will take any alternative solution

in which i dont have to install any application on my computer
like ghostscript

Comment: This is a government project in which the pdf document should have a unique id as a bar code on the top of the page . 
once the pdf is submitted its not editable to user or any other employee of the department to make it safe from changing . barcode will ensure that there has not been any changes to the page the bar code will be a unique id which will be saved in the application when the bar code of any page is scanned the application will verify that the page is not been modified and it belongs to the original pdf submitted by the user .
this is the concept of the application .

Comment: Unfortunately there is no budget to add a third party company . The way I am handling the job is what the client asked us to do .. So if there is no alternatives fast solutions to this we are stuck with the one we are using now .